# Is there a way to create a common event?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating a type of logging mechanism. The task is to log each button click and check which functionality is used the most in a production environment.

I was wondering if there is a way to create an event for all button clicks in my application including referenced projects. So when a button is clicked a central code is run after the button's click event handler.

Comment: Loop through all controls at run time and add a button click event that will handle all of those.

Comment: If you have tried anything so far would you please share what didn't work? Or are you looking for a tutorial?

Comment: @QualityCatalyst i tried multiple POCs with ideas like loop through all controls deathidmyfriend suggested and it works but i am looking for some inbuilt functionality like some base event that i can use or something that i am not aware of.

Comment: Sounds like what you want to do is create your own button class, and have it auto log that it was clicked and then pass along the clicked event to its base implementation.

Comment: @StarPilot i cant change the existing code. I am working on an existing application. I cant change the already existing buttons. Is there a way to add some default event to the existing button ?

Comment: You could use a tool like PostSharp to post process the code and to inject logging into all the buttons, but it usually works by looking at `[Attributes]` on code elements. I don't know if it's possible to tell it to just find everything of type `Button` or a derived type.  Or look at [Microsoft UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no easy way to hook code to every Click events in every buttons in your application automatically.

However, you can trap windows message, check for the click message coming from any button.

So you could use [IMessageFilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imessagefilter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) this way and do some stats about which button has been clicked.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form, IMessageFilter
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Application.AddMessageFilter(this);
    }

    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == 0x0201) // This is left click
        {
            var ctrl = Control.FromHandle(m.HWnd);
            if (ctrl is Button)
                Debug.WriteLine(ctrl.Name);
        }
        return false;

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Larry this may be very helpful to me.

Answer (score 3):

You could do a system wide filter like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.AddMessageFilter(new MyMessageFilter());  // hook filter up here

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }

    // ---- Customer Message Filter ---------

    class MyMessageFilter : IMessageFilter
    {
        public bool PreFilterMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message Msg)
        {
            const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201;

            if (Msg.Msg == WM_LBUTTONDOWN)
            {
                Control ClickedControl = System.Windows.Forms.Control.FromChildHandle(Msg.HWnd);


                if (ClickedControl != null)
                {
                    Button ClickedButton = ClickedControl as Button;

                    if (ClickedButton != null)
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("CLICK =  Form: " + ClickedButton.Parent.Text + "  Control: " + ClickedButton.Text);
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Steve. Thats exactly what I am implementing right now.

Comment: Using a separate class for message filtering the way you did is much better.

Answer (score 2):

> I was wondering if there is a way to create an event for all button clicks in my application

There is not. All other solutions are just workarounds and all have their own problems.

You could create a base form, and use that instead of the regular `Form` class you are using. In the `OnHandleCreated` you can loop over all controls, filter out the buttons and register the click event handler. (be aware of references that might cause memory issues when keeping all registered objects in memory)

Another option is to replace all button controls with an own derived version of the `Button` class that overrides the [`OnClick`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.onclick(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Comment: Thanks Patrick. I ll try to implement one of your suggestions.